# How to simulate key stroke in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, keystroke

I am trying to move my cursor to a position and fill in some numbers.
I can do move the cursor, but I cannot send the number. I used the 'clipboard' copy and paste functions. However, the program only works 1 out of 10 times

Comment: See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [This](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/gui-automation-robot) may help to send keystrokes